# system hangs when submitting answer

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I pressed submitt to answer a question.

At the same time someone else had also answered the question. The bar at the top of the screen showing that a new answer was available did not appear before I pressed submitt.

The result was that I got the bar showing a new answer was available, my answer did not appear as if it had been submitted. No buttons / links ... on the screen were active. I had to close the browser and reopen stackoverflow. My answer had been updated.

I use IE 7.

Comment: Sounds like it was a browser issue if links failed to work. If your answer was submitted I don't believe it was a bug on the SO side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a browser/local connection issue.  I have this same prob with accessing this site at work because of certain ads and scripts being blocked, which cause this site to hang up a bit. It could also just be your local connection just taking its sweet ol time.

Also, if you are running any no-script or any other similar plugins, those can have an effect once in awhile.